# Magento displays "Excl. VAT" when it should display "Inc. VAT"

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, magento-community, vat

I'm setting up my first Magento theme/install, but have an issue where the catalog/listings page is showing the price with a "Excl. VAT" label.

E.g. price entered is £8.95.
VAT rate is set to None.
***System > Config > VAT*** is set to show prices including tax everywhere, and calculate tax (not that there is any to calculate) based on the prices being entered inclusive of tax.

If anything, I'd expect it to show `Inc. VAT` based on the config, but I'd also like to be able to turn this off all together, ***in case in the future the store is VAT registered and it needs to be easily switched on.***

UPDATE:

It appears to be set via CSS, so I am now trying to find out if the CSS is determined by Magento.

The class is particular is ***.product-price-939***

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-939">
<span class="price">£19.95</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: I should have checked the output - it's being set by CSS, not by Magento. I'm trying to figure out if the CSS class is being determined programatically by Magento or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/rss/product/price.phtml` to change how pricing styles are applied.